# Recognizing email fields without using regular expressions

Tags: java, parsing, nlp

We have a tokenizer which tokenizes a text file .The logic followed is quite weird but necessary in our context.

An email such as 
`xyz.zyx@gmail.com`

will result in the following tokens :
`xyz`
`.` 
`zyx`
`@`
`gmail`

I would like to know how can we recognize the field as email if we are allowed to use only these tokens. No regex is allowed. We are allowed only to use the tokens and their surrounding tokens to figure out if the field is an email field

Comment: Why not regex? It can be done in one line using regex.

Comment: @RafiKamal because the tokenizer is an independent system which will give a stream of tokens to any requesting application. Tokenizer is independent so it doesn't fit the structure to add a regex for email recognition there

Comment: Just from the sequence of tokens you will not be able to tell the difference between "He said xyz. zyx@gmail.com is an email address." and "He said zilch. xyz.zyx@gmail.com is an email address."  You can probably get most cases right with some heuristics, but there is no way you'll be able to do this 100% correctly.

Comment: thinking of how regular expression get implemented. it might also need to separate a string into tokens and check whether the tokens string follow a given pattern. so, now you get the tokens, you will need to implement the pattern part.

Comment: what about `.` `com` tokens?

Answer (score 0):

ok.. try some (bad) logic like this...

```
  int i=0,j=0;
    if(str.contains(".") && str.contains("@"))
    {
     if((i=str.indexOf(".") < (j=str.indexOf("@")) 
    {
     if(i!=0 && i+1!=j)      //ignore Strings like .@ , abc.@ 
        return true;
    }
    }
    return false
```

Answer (score 0):

Logically split an e-mail address into 3 parts:

1. A user name (or resource name), for this explanation let's call it the user name
2. The @ character.
3. A host name, consisting of any number of "word dot" sequences + a final top level domain string.

Do a walk like this:

```
 while token can be part of a user name
    fetch next token;
    if there no more -> no e-mail;

check if the next token is @
if not -> no e-mail

while there are tokens
    while token can be part of a host name subpart (the "word" above)
        fetch next token;
        if there are no more -> might be a valid e-mail address

    check if the next token is a dot
    if not -> might be a valid e-mail address
    set a flag that you found at least one dot

   check if the next token can be part of a host name subpart
       if not -> no valid e-mail address (or maybe you ignore a trailing dot and take what was found so far)
```

Add further checks if there are more tokens where needed. You also may have to post process the found tokens to ensure a valid e-mail address and you may have to rewind your tokenizer (or cache the fetched tokens) in case you did not find a valid e-mail address and need to feed the same input to some other recognition process.

Answer (score 0):

Check if a list of tokens is an email:

- list contains exactly one token `@`
- index of token `@` != 0
- at least 3 tokens after `@`
- at least 1 `.` token after `@`, but not immediately after
- starts and ends with character tokens

Additional checks:

- no two `.` subsequent tokens
- no special characters
- length of character tokens after `@` is at least 2
- total length of all character tokens before `@` is at least 3